# How To Create New Column in Pandas Using Date/Time Information From Other Columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataset with year/month/day/hour/minute/second data stored in separate columns:

```
Day,Date,Month,Year,Hour,Min,Sec,Wind dir,WS (m/s),Press (hPa),RH (%),T(C),Td(C),SR (W/m2)
Thu,11,April,2019,16,23,27,31,1.28,993.4,38,7,-6.1,470
Thu,11,April,2019,16,24,27,103,1.21,993.5,39,7,-5.9,515
```

I have imported this from a csv file into a Pandas dataframe:

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/jacks/Downloads/Cornell/SP20/Instrumentation/Lab 5/EAS2500_MetPak11_18April2019.csv', engine='python')

I would like to create a new column in this dataframe that stores the date/time data in datetime format. I have tried this using the following code:

```
df["Date_Time"] = datetime(df["Year"],df["Month"],df["Day"],df["Hour"],df["Min"],df["Sec"])
```

But I get the following error:

```
raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

Why doesn't this work and how would I accomplish this task?

Comment: I guess month is a sting, and Pandas expects number

Comment: @Alex that seems reasonable though I thought I remembered that datetime supported references to months/days of week? Is there a way I can go through and systematically replace every instance of "April" in the "Month" column with 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df_time = df[["Year", "Month", "Date", "Hour", "Min", "Sec"]].astype(str).agg("".join, axis=1)
df["Date_Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df_time, format="%Y%B%d%H%M%S")

print(df["Date_Time"])
```

This prints:

```
0   2019-04-11 16:23:27
1   2019-04-11 16:24:27
Name: Date_Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering question in comment: how to translate month names to numbers.

Here is example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["Apr","May"], columns=["Month"])
mnth_to_num = {"Apr":4,"May":5}
df["Month_Num"] = df["Month"].apply(lambda x: mnth_to_num[x])
```

Comment: This successfully created a new column with the relevant month numbers. Thanks! But my original cannot convert the series to <class 'int'> error remains even when I reference Month_Num in the datetime function

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 df["datetime"] = df[["Year","Month","Date","Hour","Min","Sec"]].astype(str).agg('-'.join, axis=1)
 df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"],format="%Y-%B-%d-%H-%M-%S")
```

Comment: oh, I see Shubham beat me to it